# XAML designer does not work when using a WCF service

Tags: wpf, wcf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, designer

I just began doing my first steps with WCF services and made up a little WPF application that displays data retrieved from a WCF service. I split the application into two projects: a project containing the (WPF) UI and a second project containing the WCF service client.

After copying the endpoint definition from the app.config of the second project to the app.config of the first project (which is, of course, the StartUp project) the application is running now.

But since I began using the WCF service client, the XAML designer does not work anymore. It always shows the exception:

*Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyContract' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.*

This is exactly the same exception that I got before copying the endpoint definition to the other app.config file. So I guess the XAML designer doesn't use this configuration. Is it possible to fix this weird behavior? It would be okay for me if the XAML designer won't use the WCF at all (which it shouldn't do anyway IMHO) and just use some default data.

I already thought about stubbing the WCF service client in the *DesignerMode* case using RhinoMocks, but stubbing the asynchronous WCF calls isn't the easiest thing to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: how come your XAML objects are calling the wcf stuff? post your code

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Frankly, I don't now why the XAML designer calls the WCF services. I'm using a ViewModel which calls the WCF service in its constructor. Perhaps the XAML designer constructs a ViewModel object?

Comment: Yes, the designer is running the ViewModel to try and get some data for the form. See Baldewin's answer below for a work around. It's a good practice to make sure your properties are checking for design time, and possibly thow out some mock data.

Answer (score 6):

I found out how to avoid the problem: It seems that the XAML designer doesn't work if I call anything on my business object which does the WCF communication from the ViewModel's constructor (which is defined as DataContext in the main window's XAML file).

A simple

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
{
    return;
}
```

before accessing the business object makes the XAML designer work again.

Answer (score 0):

Also - the converse works; ie, by moving the service reference stuff to the 'main' app.config it can be found by the 'child' project.

Comment: The converse of what? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

My solution was to move view model assignment from `xaml` to `.cs` code file.

Step 1: remove in your xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Step 2: add to your window constructor in .cs code file:

```
DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```